# How do I switch between navigation controllers under different tabs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have an app with two different tabs, each with its own navigation controller.

Visual representation:

```
Tab controller:
  Tab 1 Navigation Controller
    ViewController1
  Tab 2 Navigation Controller
    ViewController2
```

ViewController2 is a TableViewController. Now I would like to switch from ViewController2 to ViewController1 when a row is selected.

I use a segue to connect the table cell (I'm using dynamic prototypes) directly to ViewController1. This worked, but the view is still in tab 2. I tried to solve that by also manually changing the tab as well in prepareForSegue like so:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

The problem with this approach is that when it's all done, and I tap tab 2 on my screen, it still shows ViewController1. I have to tap the tab twice to get back to ViewController2. Also, the animations are gone.

(Probably not relevant) Use Case: Tab 1 deals with cards. Tab 2 deals with decks of cards. When I select a deck in Tab 2, I want the app to switch to Tab 1 to show the cards in that deck.

tldr: I want to switch from ViewController2 to ViewController1 while also switching from Tab 2 to Tab 1. The animations should be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in animation when switching tabs in `UITabBarController`. So you can switch tabs manually using tabbar controller property `selectedIndex`.

What animation are you trying to preserve? If you want to have push animation as you would have inside same UINavigationController - I would suggest to create a separate copy of ViewController1.

Comment: That's actually not the main issue. The main issue is that there is now two copies of ViewController1, one in Tab 1 and one in Tab 2. When I switch back to Tab 2, I want it to display ViewController2, not ViewController1.

Comment: Then all you need to do is change `selectedIndex` as @sha described.  You may also need to send a message to `ViewController` so that it displays the appropriate cards

Comment: You need to pop navigation controller 2 all the way to the root when you switch page away from 2 to 1